# If a Barbarian learns Command via Fey Touched, what would the spell save DC be?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, spellcasting

I was wondering what the save DC would be for a barbarian who cast command after getting the Fey Touched feat and using it to learn command.

The Fey Touched Feat reads:

> Increase your Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma score by 1, to a maximum of 20.
>
> You learn the Misty Step spell and one 1st-level spell of your choice. The 1st-level spell must be from the Divination or Enchantment school of magic. You can cast each of these spells without expending a spell slot. Once you cast either of these spells in this way, you can’t cast that spell in this way again until you finish a long rest. You can also cast these spells using spell slots you have of the appropriate level. The spells’ spellcasting ability is the ability increased by this feat.

The Command Spell Reads:

> You speak a one-word command to a creature you can see within range. The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or follow the command on its next turn. The spell has no effect if the target is undead, if it doesn’t understand your language, or if your command is directly harmful to it. Some typical commands and their effects follow. You might issue a command other than one described here. If you do so, the DM determines how the target behaves. If the target can’t follow your command, the spell ends.

There seems to be no requirement of being a spellcaster to obtain this feat, and while Misty Step clearly doesn't require you to have a save DC, Command seems to, specifically when it says "The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or follow the command on its next turn." Am I just reading it wrong? I'm fairly new, so that's definitely a possibility.

Comment: Welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. I've closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before.

Answer (score 6):

### The DC is calculated based on your spellcasting ability and proficiency

This is on page 205, PHB:

> The DC to resist one of your spells equals **8 + your
> spellcasting ability modifier + your proficiency bonus** +
> any special modifiers.

Fey Touched allows you to pick one of Intelligence, Wisdom, Charisma to increase by +1, and this will be used as your spellcasting ability, and together with your overall proficiency bonus, will determine the DC. The last sentence of the feat description states:

> The spells’ spellcasting ability is the ability increased by this feat.

For example, assume your Barbarian is 4th level, so a proficiency bonus of +2, has a Charisma of 11 and picked Charisma as their spellcasting ability increasing it to 12, then the spellcasting ability modifier from Charisma would be +1, and their spell save DC would be **8 + 1 (Charisma Modifier) + 2 (Prof. Bonus) = 11** for the spell learned through Fey Touched.

Comment: I have downvoted because at this point in your time here, you really should be checking for duplicates before answering.

Comment: @NautArch Thank you for the explanation.